# How do I interact with PostgreSQL using CLI on a Mac?

Tags: postgresql, macos, command-line, psql, pgadmin

I've been using pgAdmin with PostgreSQL just fine but I wanted to get some practice using the command line. When I installed PostgreSQL, I made sure to include Command Line Tools. I downloaded it directly from Postgres' website - I did not use Homebrew.

From Terminal, I tried connecting using `psql` but it didn't work. So, I tried to see if I had set the path correctly as mentioned here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93369/postgres-installation-on-macosx-problem-with-psql

I used `mdfind psql` to find the path: `PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin:${PATH}"`

I reloaded the `.zprofile`, entered `psql` and my password for my current user (I also tried the PostgreSQL password) but I got the following error:

> psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "me"

I also tried changing users to "postgres" via: `sudo su - postgres` and entered in the same passwords that I previously tried but it keeps saying "Sorry, try again" and then exits after 3 attempts.

pgAdmin4 is working fine, as usual. The passwords I enter into pgAdmin are the same that I tried using Terminal. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Edit: So, it turns out that I just needed to write `sudo su postgres` without the `-`. I then entered my user password, wrote `psql`, entered the password and then I was able to interact with Postgres using the command line. If you're having difficulty as I was, try this and set the path as I did above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that I just needed to write `sudo su postgres` without the `-`. I then entered my user password, wrote `psql`, entered the password and then I was able to interact with Postgres using the command line.

If you're having difficulty as I was, try this and set the path as I did in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your PostgreSQL installation. Download https://postgresapp.com/ (or just click https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/releases/download/v2.4/Postgres-2.4-13.dmg )

Configure your `$PATH` to use the included command line tools (optional):

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d &&
echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp
```

Use `psql` for command line in Terminal. (I used Postgres.app on macOS and it worked very well.)

Reference document: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html